# Receiving Intent EXTRA_MESSAGE from Another Application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my Eclipse workspace I have my main application: A
and I have another fully functional application: B

I have configured appliction A to open up application B upon the click of a button by using an Intent and it works.

**Here is the issue:**

In application B I need to receive the EXTRA_MESSAGE. However, I am unable to access the info because application B does not recognize application A:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_DESC);
```

states that "MainActivity" cannot be resolved to a variable.

*addendum: I am working on the actual code of application B, as opening the class reference in application A gives me a uneditable display.

It seems that I would need to alter the manifest of application B, and add application A in the build path of B... this seems messy and not reusablely friendly.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

The argument to Intent.getStringExtra() is a String containing the key associated with the extended data. To get that data, you need to know the *key*, not the name of the app or Activity from which it came. Sometimes, a developer will prepend the app's package name to the key value, but the key is not likely to be the package name alone, or the name of the sending Activity, or the sending app.

If you know how the extended data was stored, find the key value and use it to retrieve the data. For an application that makes its Intents publicly available, you should be able to find this.

Otherwise, you can't retrieve the extended data, by design. This is a security feature to prevent unauthorized apps from reading data from an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a shared library between app A and B. In the project.properties file, you can mention the path of this shared lib. using `android.library.reference`

But for interprocess communication, it is better to use AIDL.

Comment: Yes, AIDL is an option. However, for two apps that share the same GUID (that is, they're from the same developer), a faster option is to send an Intent.